# Unable to disable a button when users click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added the following jquery to disable all the buttons which have a class named `.disableButton`, as follow:-

```js
$('.disableButton').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});//disable further clicks
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="disableButton btn btn-primary" />
<input type="text" class="disableButton" name="NPI" placeholder="" style="height: 50px;" />
```

but when i click on them the button will not get disabled..

Comment: Whats wrong with it?

Comment: @0stone0 the buttons will not get disabled when i  click on them...

Comment: Ow I see now, you should add a second button to the example to show the problem

Comment: which browser you are using? working fine in Mozilla

Comment: @DupinderSingh Edge, chrome and firefox

Comment: Added one answer has a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing all good, but just a little mistake that is using `this`  `this` will impact only on that specific element not all the elements

instead of `this` try this

```
        $('.disableButton').prop('disabled', true);
```

```js
    $('.disableButton').on('click', function (e) {
      alert('disabling buttons, now after this buttons will not work'); 
        $('.disableButton').prop('disabled', true);
    });//disable further clicks
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="disableButton btn btn-primary" />
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit 2" class="disableButton btn btn-primary" />
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit 3" class="disableButton btn btn-primary" />
    
    <input type="text" class="disableButton" name="NPI" placeholder="" style="height: 50px;" />
```

Comment: @testtest I updated the answer, please have a look to update one. 

Comment: have multiple buttons  with same class `disableButton` class and bootstrap in code snippet and BTW a working code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to add disabled option while clicking it. If you want to disable all the button which have the class name= disableButton you can disable by default. Use following code.

```
$(".disableButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

It will disable all the buttons by default

Comment: but still the bootstrp button did not get disabled when i click on them

Comment: try $('.disableButton').click(function (event) { event.preventDefault() });

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options there, 
1: use button id instead of a class to select it, in class selector jquery returns an array instead of the single element

2: just use `e.target.disabled = true;` //this is the native way

3: or you can do get the first element from `$(this)` which is gonna be the same with `e` from `function(e)`

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure that you script comes after your html buttons, then on your javascript, if you want all buttons or all elements that have the class disableButton to be disabled, use :

```
$('.disableButton').prop('disabled', true);
```

Isnstead of:

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Because `$(this)` applies changes only on the clicked on button.

```js
$('.disableButton').click(function (e) {
  $('.disableButton').prop('disabled', true);        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="disableButton btn btn-primary" />
<input type="text" class="disableButton" name="NPI" placeholder="" style="height: 50px;">
```

Comment: but still the bootstrp button did not get disabled when i click on them

Comment: Then share your link, maybe sthng else is making the script to not work...

Comment: @testtest also make sure that your javascript comes after the html buttons